# Look to all duplicated rows in a column and to a boolean column and set 'True' to the first if all duplicated rows are 'False' pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a database that has some Company ID's and they can be duplicated because which one was more than one contact.

I have to set 'True' to the first contact only if all contacts are set as 'False' and I didn't find how to solve this yet.

The rule is > If it's a duplicated value in Company ID column, then look if all are set as 'Não' in the 'Principal' column. If it's 'true', change the first row of 'Não' to 'Sim', if false, do nothing.

Example:

It's like that

```
ID:     Principal:
735023  Sim
735023  Não
735025  Não
735025  Não
730634  Não
730634  Não 
729074  Não
729074  Não
729074  Não
```

Then should be like that:

```
ID:     Principal:
735023  Sim
735023  Não
735025  Sim
735025  Não
730634  Sim
730634  Não 
729074  Sim
729074  Não
729074  Não
```

Someone can help me with that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this but you can try this one below. It uses a custom function with transform to return your desired output.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "ID": [735023,735023,735025,735025,730634,730634,729074,729074,729074],
    "IND": ["Sim", "Nao", "Nao", "Nao", "Nao", "Nao", "Nao", "Nao", "Nao"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
def replace_sim(data):
    if len(data) > 1 and list(data.unique()) == ["Nao"]:
        return ["Sim"] + ["Nao"]*(len(data) - 1)
    return data

df["NEW_IND"] = df.groupby("ID")["IND"].transform(replace_sim)
df
```